# Validation of Variables prior Usage

Tags: javascript, html, dom

How often should you verify or sanitize variables in JavaScript? I occasionally come across code I've written and get `Can not access property X of undefined` or similar errors. As a result, if I'm using a variable that may hold a DOM object, I've been sanitizing like below.

My question is, **how often should I be validating any variable may exist?**

Here's a sample of something I had done earlier in the week. It's purpose is to change the background colour of the a title's background based off of its text value. Please note that `__spreadArrays` is a shim for the ES6 Spread.

Is what I'm currently doing bad practice?

```
var rowColours = {
    "The Roadmap": "#5e4c79",
    // ...
    "Employee Engagement": "#00275e",
    "Stakeholder Engagement": "#00275e"
};
var sections = __spreadArrays(document.querySelectorAll(".ms-webpartPage-root .ms-webpartzone-cell"));
sections.forEach(function (o) {
    var titleBar = o.querySelector(".ms-webpart-chrome-title");
    if (!(titleBar instanceof HTMLElement))
        return;
    var titleText = titleBar ? titleBar.innerText.trim() : "";
    if (!rowColours[titleText])
        return;
    var header = o.querySelector(".ms-webpart-chrome-title > [title]");
    if (!(header instanceof HTMLElement))
        return;
    header.style.background = "linear-gradient(to right, " + rowColours[titleText] + " 50%, white 98%)";
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Always, but you can get some leverage from other tools.

There is no perfect solution for that but you should consider using `Typescript` in order to help you to get some cases like this in development/build time and also create some tests to guarantee your contracts are up to date.

As an alternative, you can use something like this:

```js
var header   = o.querySelector(".ms-webpart-chrome-title > [title]");
var newValue = "linear-gradient(to right, " + rowColours[titleText] + " 50%, white 98%)";

header instanceOf HTMLElement && header.style.background = newValue
```

I hope you find this useful.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I do normally use TypeScript, but I feel I don't use it to it's full capacity.